# Configure active zabbix agent

Tags: zabbix

I'm having trouble configuring an active zabbix agent in 2.0. If I set `DisablePassive=1` then it stops listening, but the master zabbix server just reports the node as not responding.

How exactly should I configure a node to do active checks only?

Answer (score 3):

The agent was setup correctly but the Items configured for the host need to be changed. The Type must be changed from "Agent" to "Agent Active" on all the items in the used templates. Once this change was made then it started working.

Comment: Note that the field `Type` may be not editable from most of the template views. Further explanations may be helpful.